# Picard theorem for ODE.

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem :** Let $I=]\alpha,\beta[$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ an open connexe, $(t_0,x_0)\in I\times \Omega$ and $f:I\times \Omega\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$, $f=f(t,x)$ such that:

$f\in\mathcal C^0(I\times \Omega, R^n )$

For all $J\subset I$ compact and all open $O\subset \Omega$, there is a constane $\lambda=\lambda(J,O)>0$ such that $$\forall t\in J, \forall x,y\in O,\|f(t,x)-f(t,y)\|\leq \lambda \|x-y\|.$$

Then, there exist a close interval $J\subset I$ such that $t_0\in \overset{\circ}{J}$ and $x\in\mathcal C^1(J,\Omega)$ solution of
$$\begin{cases}y'(t)=f(t,x(t)),\ t\in J\\ x(t_0)=x_0\end{cases}.$$

**Proof**

In the proof they consider $T: X\to X$ where $X\subset \mathcal C^0(J,\Omega)$  define by
$$Tx(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(\tau, x(\tau))d\tau.$$

We want to show that $$\|T x-T y\|\leq \frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|$$
for the norm $\|x\|_X=\sup_{t\in J}|x(t)|$ what will prove that $T$ has a unique fix point.

**My question (RE EDITED)**

Why do we use this specific norm ? Because in $\mathcal C^0(J,\Omega)$ all norms are not equivalent, so it's not enough to prove that if it work for this specific norm, then it work for all norms. So why the fact that $T$ has a unique fixe point for this specific norm imply that the equation has a solution on $\mathcal C^1(J,\Omega)$ (a space that doesn't has a specific norm) ?

Comment: There are some commentaries on that in the first chapter of "Introduction to nonlinear dispersive equations" by Terence Tao. The point is essentially the one outlined by timur: in the ODE setting, it does not really matter which kind of solution you find, so you just choose a functional space that works.

Answer (score 4):

Because this norm makes the function space into a complete space so that the Banach fixed point theorem is applicable.

An alternative norm with this property and giving better results, i.e., larger intervals $J$, in the proof is
$$
\|x\|=\sup_{t\in J}e^{-2 λ|t-t_0|} |x(t)|
$$

Comment: Ok, but then we only proved the theorem on $\mathcal C^0(J,\Omega)$ with the norm sup, and thus the picard theorem is only applicable on a such space. That's why I don't understand.

Comment: i think that one you know that the solution exists and $f$ is continuous then it implies that the solution is in fact $C^1.$

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the ODE setting, the notions of strong solutions and of classical solutions coincide.

Comment: Can you develop please ? I don't really understand